# SSRS BIDS SUMMING A SUM TO PRODUCE A SUM

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-expression

[image]

[image]

Please see attached images.

On the light blue row I need total percentages next to the total days.

There are 3 classifications : Project, RFC and Support, each has two sub colums (Days and Total%)

I have included a sum for total days added up which is =Sum(Fields!Days.Value)

I now need the TOTAL percentage for each of the 3 classes

Comment: What problem are you having? Did you try something and it didn't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a scope to the `SUM` to specify which `Group` to sum.

```
=Sum(Fields!Days.Value,"classification") for example.
```